# DJS v13 - Renaming a channel without any user interaction

Tags: javascript

can i ask, how to properly find channel (by id or by name) without any user input? I am doing automatic channel, which updates every 30 seconds. So, is there any chance, that I can rename channel without any user interaction in the channel I am looking for? (By far, I haven't seen any answers to this topic)
If you'd help me, I will thank you.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, include the specific expected results and the specific challenge and how we may assist you in fixing it.  What is "DJS " someone's initials? Please update your tags to give more indication on the question scope.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<TextChannel>.edit()` or `<TextChannel>.setName()` to change the channel name. More info [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=edit) for using `edit()`. More info [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setName) for using `setName()`. For example, these would work:

#### Using `<TextChannel>.edit()`

```js
// Edit a channel
channel.edit({ name: 'new-channel' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

#### Using `<TextChannel>.setName()`

```js
// Set a new channel name
channel.setName('not_general')
  .then(newChannel => console.log(`Channel's new name is ${newChannel.name}`))
  .catch(console.error);
```

**Hoped this helped!**

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, but it shows, that the channel is not defined. How to define a channel? Thanks

Comment: Whatever you have channel defined as. For example, `message.channel` or `msg.channel`